# Attempting to swap my tr tags with the prev sibling

Tags: jquery

```
$("tr #contactus_"+id).before($("tr #contactus_"+id).prev());
```

I know you can swap the position of the tr tags using this method, however I don't know the id name of the previous tr tag. What is the proper way of identifying the prev or next sibling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to know the id of the previous `tr`. `$("tr #contactus_"+id).prev()` will return it.
Note, that in both places same id is used: id of the target element.

**edit**
"*I know you can swap the position of the tr tags using this method*" part confused me and I've decided this code already works.
Two things to fix it.

1. Change [before](http://api.jquery.com/before) to [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore).
2. You don't need to specify `tr` in the selector: id already uniquely identifies element.

Also `tr #my_id` means "element `my_id` inside `tr` tag". You could use `tr#my_id` (note lack of space), but it's kinda pointless, as I said in #2.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/fy2TJ/) (with divs instead of tables for simplicity)

Comment: yes that is what I want. so $("tr #contactus_"+id) is the one being moved and $("tr #contactus_"+id).prev() is the one before it.

Comment: no, it doesnt work :) Is the code technically right? the .before part isnt working since I manually placed the id names.

Comment: @Adam It actually isn't. Since you said it already works, so I didn't look deep enough. I'll update the answer.

Comment: sorry it actually doesnt work. Perhaps it has something to do with the structure of my tables.